# Pascal Диапазон и перечислимые типы

Tags: pascal

Почему в переменную d описанную таким образом можно присвоить значение более 9, он просто ведёт себя как byte, переполняется после 255. Объясните пожалуйста в чём смысл перечислимого типа и диапазона?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Присвоить значение за пределами диапазона можно, если **отключен** контроль диапазона.

Установите `Range Checking` в настройках компилятора, оно же `{$R+}` в коде

> When enabled (equivalent to {$R+}), all array and string-indexing
> expressions are verified as being within the defined bounds, and all
> assignments to scalar and subrange variables are checked to be within
> range.